# Angular SocialAuthService google. How to close google tap (credential_picker_container)?

Tags: angular, authentication, google-chrome, google-one-tap, social-authentication

I use angular 14. Before updating I have used angular 13 with @abacritt/angularx-social-login 1.1.0, now It has been updated to ^1.2.5 and appeared one tap google auth iframe. I do auth with my own service and when client authed, we are moving to dashboard, but google tap iframe leaves on the page. I want to close it when I make auth with my own service. How to close (or disable) this? (angular 14, @abacritt/angularx-social-login ^1.2.5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your app.module.ts:

```
{
  provide: 'SocialAuthServiceConfig',
  useValue: {
    autoLogin: false,
    providers: [
      {
        id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        provider: new GoogleLoginProvider('google-id', {
          oneTapEnabled: false
        }),
      },
    ],
  } as SocialAuthServiceConfig,
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can't manipulate with this block.
But you can set in config of google-btn autoclose of this block.